# input and textarea appear different width when are set to same width?

Tags: html, css

When I set the width of an input and a text area to 94% they appear to be slightly different in width. This is something I have seen many times on many sites.

Can anyone explain why a textarea is not as wide as an input when set to the same % width?

```
input, textarea {
    width: 94%;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Don't forget [the box model](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/the-box-model-for-beginners/) includes borders, padding, and margins. They all affect the actual physical width of an element in the page.
2. Unless you use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) you're at the mercy of the default browser stylesheets which set different borders, padding, and margins for each element.

Comment: I will accept this, as when I added the padding:0 and margin:0 options the input and text area lined up. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

With CSS3 you can also use:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

Comment: I learned this a few days ago and it has changed my entire world!